# how to get records of a table from its pivot table extra field using Eloquent in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I have a web application in laravel and I have 3 tables:

1. users
2. categories
3. and a pivot table named : subscriptions

in pivot table I have these fields : UserID, CategoryID, parent_id

UserID and CatgeoryID are saving from ids of 'users' and 'categories' tables and **parent_id is the extra field**.

my models are like this:

Users table model:

```
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories','subscriptions','UserID','CategoryID')->withPivot('parent_id');
    }
```

Categories table model:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','subscriptions','CategoryID','UserID')->withPivot('parent_id');
    }
```

now My question is here that I want to **access users table records by the extra pivot field 'parent_id'**. I want to find users which have for example 'parent_id'=3 .

I want to return the records as users objects, trying this code didn't helped:

```
$category = new Categories();
$users= $category ->users()->where('parent_id','=',3)->get();
```

how can I access those users by **using eloquent**?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `where` by `wherePivot`

Example :

```
$category->users()->wherePivot('parent_id','=',3)->get();
```

Comment: I tried it several times, good news is that it gives no error; and bad news is that it doesn't return any users. it returns null. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for what you want to achieve as an end result?

```
$category = new Categories();
$category = $category->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->where('parent_id', '=', 3);
})->get();
```

**EDIT**

To get the users:

```
$category = new Categories();
$users = $category->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->where('parent_id', '=', 3);
})->get()->users;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this code does not return a user object. I don't know where I am wrong but when I want to return $users with my view it gives me error that can not get users fields.

Comment: @atiehmokhtary I see what you're trying to do. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I edited my code and this error appears : `ErrorException in FrontendController.php line 55:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$users`